# extjs grid with editable combobox column

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel to get some input from user. One of the columns is a combobox, user can select any value from the dropdown list or can provide a new value. This is the relevant part of the column model

```
{
    header: 'value',
    dataIndex: 'value',
    width: 90,
    align: 'right',
    editor: new fm.ComboBox({
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        store: selected_columns_store,
        displayField:'attr',
        minListWidth: 300,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText:'Select an attribute...',
        selectOnFocus:true
    })
}
```

I dont see any issue when user uses one of the values from dropdown list. What happens when user provides a new value is, all items in the store selected_columns_store gets deleted. Appreciate any help in fixing this

Comment: they don't get deleted... they just get fitered, you should use clearFilter() method on the store

Comment: @nscrob Yes, you are perfectly correct. everything works fine after adding clearFilter() method. Please write it in the Answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they don't get deleted... they just get filtered, you should use clearFilter() method on the store. Glad to be helpful